# Outlook Plugin SSO + onSend sample

Tags: outlook, single-sign-on, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, yo

It's been several days that I am struggling trying to create an Outlook plugin that enables SSO and that is triggered on a send event.

I am using the Yo Office generator for the SSO sample and I followed this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/tree/master/outlook-add-in-on-send) for the OnSend Event.
As they are both constructed from different manners, I have difficulties to make them work together.
SSO sample uses Webpack and OnSendEvent sample uses ReScript.

Steps to construct the SSO Sample:

```
yo office --projectType single-sign-on --host outlook --name sso-sample --js
cd sso-sample
npm install -save office-addin-sso@latest
npm run configure-sso
```

Then I did a merge between the SSO sample and the [OnSend sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/tree/master/outlook-add-in-on-send) and I run `npm start`

Steps I did to merge the two projects :

1. Merging the manifest file.
2. Adding app.js + index.html + app.css
3. inside the src folder  Modifying the webpack.js file

Here is the error I am getting :

[image]

Here is [my code](https://github.com/michwii/Outlook-Plugin-SSO-and-OnSend/tree/master).

Do you have an example that combines SSO and OnSend Event ?

Extra steps I did :

1. I trusted the localhost certificates generated by the SSO Sample.
2. I [enabled the onSend Flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=modern#enable-the-on-send-flag)

Thank you for your time and your help :)
Wish you a good day.

Comment: Have you tried checking the Network tab to see if can browser can load the addin's index.html+app.js? Are you seeing this issue in Outlook online only (have you tried either Outlook in Windows desktop or MAC)?

Comment: Also what version of Yo Office are you on (in case this is an issue with yo office being outdated)

Comment: Hi Outlook Team, thank you for your comments. 
In Chrome Dev Tab index.html and app.js are correctly loaded.
Issue in Outlook online and in Outlook Desktop Windows (don't have a mac).
Version of Yo Office : 3.1.1

Comment: We could repro this issue at our end too with the sample code provided. As of now we are investigating if this is a bug or there is somet issue with the addin itself. We will update the same on this thread soon.

Comment: Also, we wanted to understand your scenario better so that we can build better support for such cases. Can you tell us what your scenario is in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I have found from where the problem where coming from.
I have updated my code repo with a sample that works.

**Source of the issue :**
Trying to get the bootstrap token from the wrong place.
I need to call the method directly from the validatebody method.

Regards,